# how to post data to production website through local in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook-javascript-sdk, angular2-forms, web-frontend

i have a site called x(http://production.com) it and for testing purpose in need to post a question from my localhost(http://localhost:8080). For authentication i used facebook javascript sdk.

now how to login and post data into x from localhost?

PS: i'm developer of x, so i have full access of all its backend.I can enable any permission which is needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you login via facebook on your website, you receive an access token which you can see in the chrome developer tool. You can copy/paste the same token(it can be used multiple times till expiry) in your curl call for posting the question.

Comment: how can i login via facebook from localhost? i need to change the app domain name right

Comment: Do you want to post question via localhost API's/prod API's?

Comment: #xitter - got your point, login into prod app with facebook and get facebook access token use it in local calls that's it right?